# Is it possible to give a custom name to a browser window on OS X?

Tags: safari, window-manager, customization

Is it possible to give a **custom name** to a browser window on OS X?

Perhaps by using a Window Manager that has this feature? If yes, which one has it?

The **motivation** for this question is : I have 100 browser tabs open, all on different topics. It would be great to cluster these 100 browser tabs into different browser windows, each having a meaningful name.

**For example :**

- **1st** browser window for cat pictures **named "cat pictures"**, having 10 tabs open about cats
- **2nd** browser window for Haskell programming, having 10 tabs about Haskell open, **named "Haskell"**
- **3rd** browser window for Buying a new meachanical keyboard, where I have 10 different tabs open about different keyboard review sites...
  **named "keyboard"**

Any idea how to do this on OS X?

Comment: The latest version of Safari doesn't have a browser window name, just tab names.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with this extension for Firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firetitle/