# How to name Safari windows?

Tags: safari, productivity

I usually work with multiple Safari windows open. Each has multiple tabs. Each window is a particular theme. Is there a way to name these windows so I can easily navigate between them?

Or is there an app that can do it or at least provide a work around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to give a custom name to a browser window on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192242/is-it-possible-to-give-a-custom-name-to-a-browser-window-on-os-x)

Comment: Why do you want to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari names the window according to what tab is the frontmost (or selected) tab. And it gets that info from the web page itself.

You may be able to go into developer mode, and edit the HTML title attribute on a current web page (not sure, never tried this) but as the name of the window changes with what tab is selected not sure you would find this acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround, not a solution, and probably very obvious for most.

I put a tab leftmost in the window and do a DuckDuckGo search for what I would want to title the window, usually with a number at the front. So, for example "1 Running" "2 Career Coaching" "3 Bagpipes". As long as I remember to click into that tab before I switch away (easily the biggest problem with this workaround), it works pretty well, and I would say I manage some 60-70% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Tab Groups (https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/group-tabs-ibrwa2d73908/mac) will do this, at least on newer versions of Safari.

Create a group for each window and give it a name according their theme it'll show up in the title displayed in the Window menu: "Theme — Tab Title"

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late for the party, but I had the need today as well.

What I found out is, that you can set the document.title of your tab using JavaScript. When switching tabs, the changed name will be taken when you return to the tab.

In my example I only required one tab, so my approach is this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    -- get the window I want to change the name of
    set playerwin to first window whose name starts with "RVR"

    -- Prepend "Web Player - " to the document title
    do JavaScript "
        document.title = 'Web Player - " & (name of playerwin) & "';
    " in document 1

    -- open & close an empty tab
    tell playerwin
        set current tab to (make new tab)
        close current tab
    end tell

    -- get the properties. Name should be changed now
    return properties of playerwin
end tell
```

Comment: I would like to use this solution, but I'm not sure where this should be placed, or how one might dynamically change the title.

Comment: I would like to answer your question but I'm not sure what it means.